# Unable to click radio element in a browser (using Python 3 and Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working in Python 3 and using Selenium to click on a radio button in a browser. I am able to locate the Radio Element to be clicked. However, when I do `Element.click()`, it gives me an error:

```
Message: unknown error: Element <Description of Element> is not clickable at point (340, 190).

Other element would receive the click: <Description of some other element>.
```

The radio element, as it appears in browser is:

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="Promoter" name="Type" onchange="Checkboxck(&#39;Promoter&#39;)" type="radio" value="Promoter" />
```

My code to find this radio element and click on it is:

```
Registered_Project_RadioButton = browser.find_element_by_id("Promoter")
Registered_Project_RadioButton.click()
```

Comment: You need to either dismiss the other element or wait until it's gone, e.g. a Loading... popup, floating header, dialog, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use Actions Class or Java Script Executor to achieve this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

Registered_Project_RadioButton = browser.find_element_by_id("Promoter")
ActionChains(browser).move_to_element(Registered_Project_RadioButton).click().perform()
```

OR

```
Registered_Project_RadioButton = browser.find_element_by_id("Promoter")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", Registered_Project_RadioButton)
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK. The first option did not work but the second solution did. Thanks..:)